# Test Fragment not executing Timers or Sample Timeout

Tags: timer, jmeter

I add in JMeter [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) with `Sample Timeout` and Timers but without any Samplers.

I add a Module controller using this Test Fragment in Thread Group with Samplers in same hierarchy (before and after, also HTTP samplers).

I expected that the Timers and `Sample Timeout` will work on every Sample in scope but no timeout/delay is been done,

Also I notice that Sampler can be a child of `Module controller` but it won't be executed (or Timers).

It seems like a bug, but maybe there are scoping rules I missed?

- Other Pre Processor as `User Parameters` are working so I wonder why timeout is ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is indeed due to scoping rules.

Your Test Fragment is like a Controller, all elements it contains are applied to its scope.
Since it doesn't contain any sampler here, neither the timer nor the other pre/post processor run.

Note that ability of adding such useless elements will be removed in upcoming 4.0 version:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61965

Comment: In latest version 4 RC I can still add test fragment with only pre processor in use module controller to include it. it's not a major issue for me. but there should be a bug to track it

Comment: Hello, please open one then. Thanks