# Can you add JMeter Listeners and Config elements into a TestFragment?

Tags: jmeter

I've had some experience with JMeter and haven't used for about 3-4 years.   I'm experimenting with modularizing our JMeter script by putting the config chunks (User Defined Data) and listener elements into a Test Fragment which could then be included into the main scripts using an Include Controller.

Is this possible?  Has anyone tried this?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078118/test-fragment-not-executing-timers-or-sample-timeout?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/):

1. [Configuration Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements)  - yes
2. [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) - no (unless you have any [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the Test Fragment)